# How do I select a double-size UID (7-Bytes) using the reader IC MFRC500?

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare

For this explanation please follow attached image. It explains the communication loop for selecting an NFC card.

I am trying to read the 7-bye UID from a Mifare Classic 1k card. So far, I have managed to read the cascade tag (0x88) and first 3-bytes of the UID. I have also received the first SAK response (0x04) from the card.

However, when sending the SEL2 (0x95) and NVB (0x20) bytes I am not receiving a response from the card. Hence, my card reader (MFRC500) is stuck in receive.

Any suggestions or tips on what to check to find the issue?

Thank you in advance.

[image]